Do 角立つ and 角が立つ have difference meanings?
あの時のお前がラブホで雑談だけ...
角立つ言い方だな。オイ
So the character in the first line comments that basically "You went to a love hotel but the only thing you did was talking" in a shocked tone.
So the other character replies 角立つ言い方だな。オイ. What is 角立つ? Means "sharp, rough" but 角が立つ means something like "to create hard feelings"?

Have you checked a monolingual definition?

There is no such a verb as 角立つ. Simply, が has been omitted after 角. 角が立つ is a set phrase explained in any dictionary.

That's puzzling. 角立つ is listed on Jisho.org, which I wouldn't necessarily trust, but it's also on Weblio, which I had assumed was reputable. I guess it's just very rare then: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A7%92%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4

@user3856370 Oh, I didn't know such a word existed. BCCWJ has two instances of 角立つ from the same author born in 1927, but this means 角立つ is virtually nonexistent today.
